# Finding a distribution to fit this curve

Tags: functions, curves, data-analysis

If it is possible, could someone help me fit some kind of function to this curve? I thought a Lorentzian fit would work because of the peak and the tails, but it is causing problems. I will attach an image of the curve below.
[image]
Image of the general curve. The function used to fit the graph doesn't have to be perfect, but it should encompass the peak, with the right-hand tail included

Comment: You want a *density* function to fit that curve? The area under that is certainly more than one...

Comment: The axis says frequency so maybe you could give some context? That way someone could say what the expected function would be.

Comment: This is a plot of magnitude of impedance against frequency of AC voltage

Comment: Also the peak is a resonant peak, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try fitting a curve of the form $$a \exp(-(x-b)^2) + c x + d$$

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try now

Comment: That captures what's going on on the right tail well, but there's still a problem with the actual peak Thank you for the help though

Comment: Another option is [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) - it can look like Gaussian if the mean is large, but it has support $[0,\infty)$ instead of $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: I'll give it a go